# Find explicit value of ${{u}_{x}}$ and ${{u}_{y}}$ of Burgers equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the first order  quasi-linear equation with initail condition for a function $u(x,y)$ of two variables $x, y$ :

$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & {{u}_{y}}+u{{u}_{x}}=0 \\ 
 & u\left( x,0 \right)=h\left( x \right)\text{ },\text{    }x\in R \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$

where $h:R\to R$ is a smooth increasing function with $h(5)=80$, ${h}'(5)=3$.  Find the values of ${{u}_{x}}\left( 165,2 \right)$ and ${{u}_{y}}\left( 165,2 \right)$.

**My attempt:**

By method of characteristics, we get:

$$u\left( x,y \right)=h\left( x-uy \right)$$

and also

$${{u}_{x}}=\frac{{h}'\left( x-uy \right)}{1+{h}'\left( x-uy \right)y}$$ 
$${{u}_{y}}=\frac{-u{h}'\left( x-uy \right)}{1+{h}'\left( x-uy \right)y} .$$
By observation, we can get

$$80=u(165,2)=h(165-u(165,2)2)=h(5)=80 $$
and solve ${u}_{x},{u}_{y}$ accordingly.

Is there a way to derive $u(165,2)=80$ instead of "by observation"?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think there is any other way since you lack the information needed to perform the usual trace-back to initial data. For a general point $(x, y)$, you have no idea what the corresponding characteristic equation is. The only thing you can do is follow the $x_5(y) = 5 + h(5) \cdot y = 5 + 80 \cdot y$ characteristic and observe that it goes through the point $(165, 2)$.